# ANSIBLE: Looping over complex dict using several variables

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I want to be able to determine the average size of a particular list of directories over a number of hosts. I start on the hosts by finding the directories i want, evaluating their size and putting the results in a nice dict:

```yaml
  - name: find log dirs
    shell: "find / -type d -name 'log' 2>/dev/null | sort"
    register: log_list

  - name: evaluate dir sizes
    shell: "du -sk {{ item }} | awk '{ print $1 }'"
    register: folder_size 
    loop : "{{ log_list.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: build dict
    set_fact:
      folder_info: "{{ folder_info|default({}) | combine({item.item: {'path': item.item, 'size': item.stdout|int}}) }}"
    loop: "{{ folder_size.results }}"
```

Back on the Ansible controller i put all those dicts together in a nice big dict, and also put together a list of dirs:

```yaml
  - name: gather folder info
    set_fact:
      all_dirs: "{{ all_dirs|default([]) + hostvars[item].dir_list|unique }}"
      all_folder_info: "{{ all_folder_info|default({}) | combine({hostvars[item].inventory_hostname:hostvars[item].folder_info}) }}"
    loop: "{{ groups['backoffice'] }}"
```

Debugging all_folder_info gives me something like this:

```json
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all_folder_info": {
        "some.host.com": {
            "/some/directory/": {
                "path": "/some/directory",
                "size": 220
            },
            "/some/other/directory": {
                "path": "/some/other/directory",
                "size": 8
            },
            "/some/third/directory": {
                "path": "/some/third/directory",
                "size": 319404
            }
        },
```

I now need to iterate over this huge dict to extract the info i want and do math on it, but i'm stuck. I tried zipping like this, that Ansible says can't template:

```yaml
  - name: debug
    debug: 
      var: (all_folder_info[item.0].[item.1].size | sum) / (all_folder_info[item.0].[item.1].size | length)
    loop: "{{ groups['backoffice']|zip_longest(all_dirs|unique)|list }}"
```

This seems to at best just put the two lists into key:value pairs. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're trying to get at the end, let me know if I've misunderstood. For every host in the `backoffice` group, you want to print out the average directory size by looking up that host in `all_folder_info[someHost]`.

Comment: That's correct. So my instinct is i need to loop both on [someHost] and [someDir] to achieve that...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid needing to do a nested loop, we can make use of filters to get the value we want for a single host. This snippet should give you what you want.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }} average size: {{ all_folder_info[item].values() | map(attribute='size') | sum / all_folder_info[item] | length }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['backoffice'] }}"
```

To break it down:

The `all_folder_info['some.host.com']` right now is a dict, but I would prefer a list of just the values so that I can use the `map` filter to manipulate it. I found that you can do `.values()` to return a list of values without the keys -- `all_folder_info['some.host.com'].values()`:

```json
[
  {"path": "/some/directory", "size": 220},
  {"path": "/some/other/directory", "size": 8},
  {"path": "/some/third/directory", "size": 319404}
]
```

Then applying the `map` filter on it to extract just the `size` attribute -- `all_folder_info['some.host.com'].values() | map(attribute='size') | list`:

```
[220, 8, 319404]
```

Since the list only contains integers, we can then use the `sum` filter to sum up the total over the list.

Comment: Thanks for that ! I was struggling to use the map filter earlier, and using .values() makes all the difference.
However, the final result is the average of all the log dirs per host. Can you think of a way i could also loop on the 'path' value ? Maybe in a when: ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to display the average size of a `/some/directory` across all hosts instead? If so, might be difficult with the current all_folder_info structure. Maybe if the structure of all_folder_info can be changed so the path is the key.

Comment: That's right. Do you mean something in the form of
```all_folder_info: [some_host: { path:size}]``` ?